# How to ensure the subscriptionId can be found when trying to Monitor Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azureportal, azure-monitoring

I am working on this: [Monitor Azure AD B2C with Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/azure-monitor). I am sort of blocked in doing this now as I do not get any further than step 3.3.3 which requires me to press a button in order to create and ARM template. Pressing the button is simple but filling the form in a way that does not result in an error, is not that simple.

[image]

The "Managed by Tenant Id" part was filled in with the Id found in 3.1 . The value of `principilId` is the objectId of the security group selected in 3.2 .

It may all sound logical. But I got an error when trying to proceed. Here is the full json of this error:

```json
{
  "code": "InvalidTemplateDeployment",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "InvalidManagedServicesTemplateDeployment",
      "message": "The managed services template deployment file contains invalid values. Please see details.",
      "details": [
        {
          "code": "ClassicAdministratorListFailed",
          "message": "Failed to list classic administrators of subscription '6f579c77-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-762dae90xxxx': 'The subscription ID was not found.'."
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "message": "The template deployment 'Microsoft.Template-2023120514xxxx' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is 'fbb904b5-xxxx-xxxx--xxxx-0425aa10xxxx'. See inner errors for details."
}
```

Apparently, it can't find my `subscriptionId`. This is strange because when I type `az account show`, this is presented as my default subscription.

So how do I convince this tooling to find it?

Answer (score 0):

> The error might occur if the user does not have **`Owner`** role under subscription while deploying the template, that is required to onboard **Azure Lighthouse**.

In my case, I got *similar error* when I tried to deploy the resource with user having **Contributor** role under subscription:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to assign **`Owner`** role to the user account under your subscription like this:

[image]

When I tried the same with user having **Owner** role, deployment is successful where Azure Lighthouse created:

[image]

To confirm that, you can check **`Delegations`** tab in **Service providers** like this:

[image]

You can now add **Diagnostic setting** in your Azure AD B2C tenant to configure monitoring and proceed to remaining steps:

[image]

**Reference:**
[ClassicAdministratorListFailed · Azure-Lighthouse-samples · GitHub by **Kristian Nese**](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Lighthouse-samples/issues/40)